# Enabling Swagger springdoc-openapi-ui (OpenAPI 3.0) with Spring Security - Cannot access swagger-ui.html (401)

Tags: java, spring-security, openapi, user-roles, springdoc

## Swagger OpenAPI 3.0 is working with springdoc-openapi-ui and a custom OpenAPI Bean.

pom.xml

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>Hoxton.SR10</version>
</parent>
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

SwaggerConfig:
[image: Custom OpenAPI Bean]

## The problem with spring-security with the same configuration

We are facing a problem, when using springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-openapi-security together with spring-boot-starter-security and keycloak-spring-boot-starter.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-security</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
      <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>12.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

DummySecurityConfig (profile dev is used currently):

```
@Profile({"test", "dev"})
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true,
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true)
@EnableWebMvc
public class DummySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    protected static final String[] ACTUATOR_WHITELIST = {
        "/actuator/**"
    };

    protected static final String[] SWAGGER_WHITELIST = {
        "/v3/api-docs/**",
        "/swagger-ui/**",
        "/swagger-ui.html",
    };

    @Value("${client.cors.allowed-origins:*}")
    private String[] allowedOrigins;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic(); //or anything else, e.g. .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers(SWAGGER_WHITELIST)
                .antMatchers(ACTUATOR_WHITELIST);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new AuthenticationProvider() {
            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
                SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + authentication.getPrincipal().toString().toUpperCase());

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        authentication.getPrincipal(), authentication.getCredentials(), Collections.singleton(authority));
                token.setDetails(authentication);
                return token;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        return authenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig (Not used in the examples but will be used in the future too):

```
@Profile({"staging", "devstaging"})
@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    prePostEnabled = true,
    securedEnabled = true,
    jsr250Enabled = true)
@EnableWebMvc
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    protected static final String[] ACTUATOR_WHITELIST = {
        "/actuator/**"
    };

    protected static final String[] SWAGGER_WHITELIST = {
        "/v3/api-docs/**",
        "/swagger-ui/**",
        "/swagger-ui.html",
    };

    @Value("${client.cors.allowed-origins:*}")
    private String[] allowedOrigins;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthorityMapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
        grantedAuthorityMapper.setConvertToUpperCase(true);
        grantedAuthorityMapper.setPrefix("ROLE_");

        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(grantedAuthorityMapper);
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(SWAGGER_WHITELIST)
            .antMatchers(ACTUATOR_WHITELIST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors().and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins);
    }
}
```

application-dev.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8083
  servlet:
    context-path: /planning
keycloak:
  enabled: false
springdoc:
  show-actuator: true
```

We already tried to use following links to solve the problem:

- [Spring security support](https://springdoc.org/#spring-security-support)
- [Allow anonymous access to springdoc-openapi-ui with Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59898402/allow-anonymous-access-to-springdoc-openapi-ui-with-spring-security)
- [Swagger UI redirecting to /swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62044228/swagger-ui-redirecting-to-swagger-ui-index-htmlconfigurl-v3-api-docs-swagger)
- [F.A.Q](https://springdoc.org/faq.html)

### Examples of opening the swagger-ui URLs (profile dev):

http://localhost:8083/planning/swagger-ui.html (does not work):
[image: http://localhost:8083/planning/swagger-ui.html]

Code snippet of application:

```
2021-03-05 09:27:01,530 [http-nio-8083-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/planning] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name 'redirect:/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/planning/v3/api-docs/swagger-config' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'redirect:/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/planning/v3/api-docs/swagger-config' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1077)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
```

http://localhost:8083/planning/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/planning/v3/api-docs/swagger-config (works but is complicated):
[image: http://localhost:8083/planning/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/planning/v3/api-docs/swagger-config]

http://localhost:8083/planning/swagger-ui/index.html (Adding api-docs "/planning/v3/api-docs" manually works too):
[image: http://localhost:8083/planning/swagger-ui/index.html]

Do you have any ideas what else could be wrong configured or what we should change? We are at the end of our latin.

Comment: 2 things: 1. Since it looks like you are using Swagger V3, **the correct URL** should be `http://localhost:8083/planning/swagger-ui/index.html`, **V2 will use** `/swagger-ui.html` if you are using default settings. 2. If the configUrl is not picked up automatically you can try setting the properties described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73928258/9520479

Answer (score 0):

As the log says, `Could not resolve view with name 'redirect:/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=**/planning/v3/api-docs/swagger-config'**`.
In your web security configuration you only give access to /v3/api-docs/**.
Try to add /planning/** or modify the path.

Comment: Thank you @user15400529 for answering and your tips but unfortunately it did not work.

1. I added /planning/ to **SWAGGER_WHITELIST** and also to configure(HttpSecurity http) {http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", **"/planning/"**, "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll().} Still the 401 status code appears.

2. I tried to adapt the springdoc.swagger-ui.configUrl property and set the value to /v3/api-docs/swagger-config. However, I think that the context-path (e.g. /planning in my case) is already used as prefix for all URL properties.

Comment: In both cases the same exception **Could not resolve view with name 'redirect:/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/planning/v3/api-docs/swagger-config' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'** appeared.

Do you know any other approaches/configuration to solve that?